# Почему не выводятся данные из таблицы python sqlalchemy + postgresql?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Почему не выводит запись из базы в row?

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, Table, Column, Integer, String, select
from sqlalchemy import text
from config import config

def dbAccCheck(id):
    params = ({"user": id})
    connection_string = f'postgresql+psycopg2://{config.user_db}:{config.pass_db}@{config.host_db}/{config.name_db}'
    engine = create_engine(connection_string)
    connection = engine.connect()
    metadata = MetaData()
    metadata.reflect(bind=engine)
    table = metadata.tables['user']

    query = select(table).where(table.c.user == id)
    result = connection.execute(query)

    if result:
        print(f" есть запись {result}")
    if not result:
        print(f" пусто")

    for row in result:
        print(row)

    connection.close()
```

print>> есть запись <sqlalchemy.engine.cursor.CursorResult object at 0x000002471CDD7520>

в базе есть одна запись

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.CursorResult.all

Comment: fetchone надо делать, execute не возвращает записи

Comment: AttributeError: 'Connection' object has no attribute 'fetchone'

Comment: cursor = connection.cursor() и потом уже от курсора делать и execute и fetchone

Comment: Хотя можно и ваш вариант, вроде result.all() должен выдать результаты